# How to fill an object constructor by querying a DB in Java

Tags: java, resultset

I am trying to make a UserInfo object constructor by querying a database and I keep getting the `cannot find symbol` error for the `UserInfo thisUserInfo = new UserInfo()` part. I am trying to take the `ResultSet rs` and fill in the constructor to make a "session" for a user who logs in.

What am I doing wrong here? Here is my code:

```
private UserInfo getUserInfo(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException {
    String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
    String nullString = null;
    char nullChar = ' ';

    ResultSet rs = null;

    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String getInfoSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + studentsTable + " WHERE USERNAME = '" + userName + "'";
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(getInfoSQL);
    if(rs.next()) {
        UserInfo thisUserInfo = new UserInfo(rs.getString(userName), rs.getString(passWord), rs.getString(lastName), rs.getString(firstName), rs.getString(age), rs.getString(sex), rs.getString(email));
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
    } else {
        UserInfo thisUserInfo = new UserInfo(nullString, nullString, nullString, nullString, nullString, nullChar, nullString);
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
    }
    return thisUserInfo;
}
```

Here is my UserInfo class:

```
public class UserInfo {
private final String userName;
private final String passWord;
private final String lastName;
private final String firstName;
private final String age;
private final char sex;
private final String email;

public UserInfo(String userName, String passWord, String lastName, String firstName, String age, char sex, String email) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.passWord = passWord;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.age = age;
    this.sex = sex;
    this.email = email;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return this.userName;
}
public String getPassWord() {
    return this.passWord;                
}
public String getLastName() {
    return this.lastName;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
}
public String getAge() {
    return this.age;    
}
public char getSex() {
    return this.sex;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return this.email;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% about everything, but this looks wrong to me...

```
if(rs.next()) {
    // UserInfo is declared within a local context
    UserInfo thisUserInfo = new UserInfo(rs.getString(userName), rs.getString(passWord), rs.getString(lastName), rs.getString(firstName), rs.getString(age), rs.getString(sex), rs.getString(email));
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
} else {
    // UserInfo is declared within a local context
    UserInfo thisUserInfo = new UserInfo(nullString, nullString, nullString, nullString, nullString, nullChar, nullString);
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
}
// thisUserInfo does not exist
return thisUserInfo;
```

It should be more like...

```
UserInfo thisUserInfo = null;
if(rs.next()) {
    thisUserInfo = new UserInfo(rs.getString(userName), rs.getString(passWord), rs.getString(lastName), rs.getString(firstName), rs.getString(age), rs.getString(sex), rs.getString(email));
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
} else {
    thisUserInfo = new UserInfo(nullString, nullString, nullString, nullString, nullString, nullChar, nullString);
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
}
return thisUserInfo;
```

Mind you, I would personally do it more like....

```
try {
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String getInfoSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + studentsTable + " WHERE USERNAME = '" + userName + "'";
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(getInfoSQL);
    UserInfo thisUserInfo = null;
    if(rs.next()) {
        thisUserInfo = new UserInfo(rs.getString(userName), rs.getString(passWord), rs.getString(lastName), rs.getString(firstName), rs.getString(age), rs.getString(sex), rs.getString(email));
    } else {
        thisUserInfo = new UserInfo(nullString, nullString, nullString, nullString, nullString, nullChar, nullString);
    }
} finally {
    try {
        rs.close();
    } catch (Exception exp) {
    }
    try {
        rs.close();
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        stmt.close();
    }
}
return thisUserInfo;
```

As has (now) been pointed out...`UserInfo` expects a `char` for the `sex` parameter but you are passing it a `String`

You should try extract the value from the database using something like `String sexValue = rs.getString(sex)` and if it's not null, use `sexValue.getCharAt(0)`.

I also have no idea where `userName`, `passWord`, `lastName`, `firstName`, `age`, `sex` and `email` are defined.  This concerns me a little...

Comment: Thanks, MadProgrammer. So where should I define `userName`, `passWord`, etc.? In the `getUserInfo()` method?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, kept getting dragged away from the computer.  The variables you're using to extract the results from the resultset, ie `rs.getString(userName)` aren't defined anywhere (I can see), which just worries me a little ;)

Comment: I see... So I have just changed the constructor parameters so that I just take the nth data like this: `UserInfo thisUserInfo = new UserInfo(rs.getString(0), rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5).atChar(0), rs.getString(6))`. Would this work just fine?

Comment: I could be mistaken (been awhile since I was able to work with a real database), but I think the `ResultSet` values start at `1` not `0` ;)

Comment: Oh my.. You are right! Thanks! One more question, do you know how I could add another servlet to my web.xml file?

Comment: Wow, it's been years since I even looked at servlets :P - Off the top of my head, no...

Answer (score 2):

You need to post the code for your `UserInfo` class for starters.  I would bet though that you don't have a constructor defined that takes those parameters.

**Edit** You're trying to implicitly convert from a `String` to a `char` which I suspect you can't do.  Instead of `rs.getString(sex)` try `rs.getChar(sex)`.  Alternatively you could add an additional constructor that accepts a `String` for the sex parameter.

**Edit** Oh, I see the issue now.  You've never defined any of the other variables, like `passWord` etc.  Those need to be Strings for the column names or ints for the column indexes.

Also, this is unrelated, but never pass unsanitized input in a query like that. You're opening yourself up for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use [prepared statements instead](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)
 or make sure you escape the input at the very least.

Comment: Just edited the question, Chris. Please take a look. And I know I'm supposed to use `PreparedStatements` but I'll worry about that later. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Since I have `String userName = request.getParameter("userName")` up top, because that is the only parameter I need from my jsp page, errors occur on all other `rs.getString()` methods saying `cannot find symbol`. What's the problem?

Comment: I see... So I have just changed the constructor parameters so that I just take the nth data like this: `UserInfo thisUserInfo = new UserInfo(rs.getString(0), rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getChar(5), rs.getString(6))`. This seems like it would work but `rs.getChar()` doesn't exist so I did `rs.getString(5).charAt(0)`. Would this work as well?

Comment: @Dinky Yep, `charAt` is a great way to do it.  I'm not sure what number the column indexes start at, I usually use column names but that is how you would do it.